# How to create speech recognition object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I want to create a speech recognition object in JavaScript, but when I am going code this:

```
const btn =document.querySelector(".talk");
const containt=document.querySelector(".containt");
const SpeechRec=window.SpeechRecognition||window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition= new SpeechRecognition(); //Error in this line ``
```

it gives an error that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined at script.js:6
```

Answer (score 0):

To use speech recognition in an app, you need to specify the following permissions in your manifest:

```
"permissions": {
  "audio-capture" : {
    "description" : "Audio capture"
  },
  "speech-recognition" : {
    "description" : "Speech recognition"
  }
}
```

You also need a privileged app, so you need to include this as well:

```
  "type": "privileged"
```

Are you doing all this?

NB: Taken from...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition

In other words, you are attempting to call a special function that is part of a Chrome/Mozilla collaboration library for modern browsers (not standard javascript) so you must have a manifest.json file in your project’s directory in which you have to declare all these optional libraries you will be utilizing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in having speech recognition work in more browsers, including Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc... You can use Microsoft's Speech SDK. There are some good samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/browser

Answer (score -2):

[This has a very good example for Speech Recognition in JS](https://davidwalsh.name/speech-recognition)

While the above link is a guide. The error in the code the SpechRecognition JS variable is referenced incorrectly. The actual reference name is "SpeechRec". Please see the below corrected code -

```
const btn =document.querySelector(".talk");
const containt=document.querySelector(".containt");
const SpeechRec=window.SpeechRecognition||window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition= new SpeechRec();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24874027)

Comment: Sure - that makes sense - noted.